# google chrome extension message passing response function not setting variable in global scope

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, message-passing

I'm trying to use message passing to get data and return it, but for some reason when I tell the response function to set a variable in a higher scope, it isn't doing it. here is my code:

```
function getSwapOptions(){
    var options = [];
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({method: "getSwapOptions"}, function(response){
        options = JSON.parse(response.data);
    });
    console.log(options);
    return options;
}
```

anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` is asynchronous meaning it will not wait for it to finish before continuing the rest of your code. This will result in you logging and returning `undefined`

Comment: @BeardFist is there a another function that I can use that is synchronous?

Comment: No, you'll just have to redesign your code to work with it being asynchronous.